# Firbase flutter, [firebase_auth/channel-error] Unable to establish connection on channel

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

when trying to user Firbase Auth to authenticate a user, Firebase Throws the Followning FirebaseAuthException
`[firebase_auth/channel-error] Unable to establish connection on channel.`

Firebase initialzises without any problem

```dart
try {
    UserCredential userCredential = await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      email: email, 
      password: password
    );
    return userCredential.user!=null;
} on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
    print(e);
    onAuthError(e);
    return false;
} catch (e) {
    return false;
}
```

SPEC:
FLutter: 3.13.5
cloud_firestore: ^4.9.2
firebase_auth: ^4.10.0
firebase_database: ^10.2.6

I am expecting the run the code without errors and getting logged in with no problem.

Comment: Is this error solved?

Answer (score 3):

Found the Problem:
I accidentally sent an empty email address and an empty password. Plus, I used the wrong android version.

Comment: same here, i sent empty otp

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the following dependecies then replace it with a latest version:
firebase_messaging
firebase_core
flutter_local_notifications

Then in android/app/build.gradle update compileSdkVersion to 33

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).